# UI is not updating after data change in vue

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

When I have used the array directly (without making it part of the object) then it's working fine as expected,
below is the code,

```
<span class="tagSpan" v-else-if="row.label == 'Tags'">
    <span v-if="aTags.length" v-for="(tag, tagIndex) in aTags" class="input-tag tagSpan">{{tag}}                                           
        <span class="close-x" @click="aTags.splice(tagIndex, 1)">❌</span>
    </span>
    <input  v-on:keyup.186="onTagAdd(rowIndex)" type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm col-3" :disabled="!row.editable" v-model="row.value" >
</span>
```

Now I optimized the code and made aTags is an item of oDyData object and changed the code as below

```
<span class="tagSpan" v-else-if="row.label == 'Tags'">
    <span v-if="oDyData.aTags && oDyData.aTags.length" v-for="(tag, tagIndex) in oDyData.aTags" class="input-tag tagSpan">{{tag}}                                           
        <span class="close-x" @click="oDyData.aTags.splice(tagIndex, 1)">❌</span>
    </span>
    <input  v-on:keyup.186="onTagAdd(rowIndex)" type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm col-3" :disabled="!row.editable" v-model="row.value" >
</span>
```

**My function for removing tag '@click="aTags.splice(tagIndex, 1)' is not working as before**, It removes the item from the array of the object but UI is not getting updating, I have also cross-checked in vue development components and the array is getting updated but UI is not getting rerendered (updating) until any other change in UI (It got changes if I enter something in input or click somewhere). Below is the screenshot for the same.
[image: Tag UI]

How to solve this?

Comment: It would help if you add (more) complete code, so that the problem is reproducible. Now you aren't getting answers, but guesses. See help for [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](/help/mcve).

Comment: Okay, will try to do it on jsbin.

Answer (score 0):

```
<span class="close-x" @click="aTags.splice(tagIndex, 1)">❌</span>
```

use `@click="oDyData.atags.splice(tagIndex,1)`

Because you are trying to reach aTags object which is undefined because you are getting this object from oDyData. O this might be the problem in your code. Also you have to use `:key` while using `v-for` property.

Comment: Sorry, I have done mistake while copy paste, updated the question with the correct function name.